# Can I create a trigger to run a check before DROP DATABASE

Tags: mysql

I want to add a little extra security to my databases just in case some other developer calls a "drop database" by accident on an active customer schema.

Is it possible in MySQL to add a trigger to a schema/database so as it causes an error if a test proves the schema is active (the test is not important, it's just a basic SQL statement)?

Comment: What does it mean for a schema to be "active"?

Comment: The only triggers you can create are before/after `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`. There are no triggers on `DROP DATABASE`.

Comment: Revoke DROP privileges

Comment: Revoking DROP privileges won't help, I want to add an extra safeguard to prevent accidental deletion by users with the DROP privilege